# Particle System is Static at the Origin Point (Bullets for a gun)

Tags: rendering

[image]

The particle system is bunching up at the origin point in the rendered image. The rectangular red glow to the left of the robot's gun is the issue I'm talking about.

Comment: did u parent the ps object to your gun? if not, pls provide blend file, because we have no idea how you set up your scene

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create an emitter (plane), set emit from faces, particles/face to 1.

Adjust your number as you like it, give it some more velocity on normal, set field weights gravity to zero or low value.

Parent your emitter to your gun.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Setting particles/face to 1 fixed the issue.